# Macro with two arguments SAS 9.4

Tags: macros, sas

I have a table with 4 variables: State (Alabama, Arizona and Arkansas), County, PovertyRate and PopulationDensity. I want a short macro with two arguments(state and county) that will print the data for any state/county combo. I came up with the following code which I tested for Covington county in Alabama and it gave me what it was supposed to but not sure if this is the most efficient/correct way to create this macro? Any feedback/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
%macro state_county(state,county);  
  data NEW3;
    set NEW; 
    where state="&state"; 
  run; 
  data new4; 
    set NEW3; 
    where county="&county"; 
  proc print data=NEW4 NOOBS; 
  run; 
%mend state_county; 

%state_county(Alabama,Covington);
```

Comment: Do you actually need to create an output data set, or just want to print it?

Comment: Just need to print the data for any state/county combination.

Comment: what happens if your counties do not match to state.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to print, then only have a PRINT. You can put the WHERE directly into PROC PRINT, as either it's own statement or a data set option. If you have large data a data set option can be more efficient.

```
%macro state_county(state,county);

proc print data=NEW NOOBS; 
where state="&state" and county="&county"; 
run; 

%mend state_county; 



 %state_county(Alabama,Covington);
```

Comment: That was actually what I tried doing at first but for whatever reason, it keeps throwing an error "ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "STATE_COUNTY".
1                            where state="&state" and county="&county";
                             -----
                             180

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I just got it to work, I needed to delete the "and" and instead just write two where statements, one for state and one for county. Thank you!

Comment: No, that's not right. If you have two WHERE statements only the last one is valid. WHERE with AND should be fine, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Hm, that's odd.. My SAS seems to be buggy because now I just tried it again the way you suggested and it works. It seems like everytime I close my SAS and then open it again, something new happens with the same old code lol

Comment: Since you are doing a string comparison, you will also want to ensure that you handle any potential differences in case (upcase, lowcase, mixed case, etc.).  "Alabama" is not equal to "ALABAMA", for example.